# How to configure Nginx to prevent Nginx errors when accessing restricted or non-existing files?

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have Nginx 1.18 installed on Ubuntu 22.04.

`example.com/non-existing-route` returns Laravel's 404 error, while

`example.com/_ide_helper.php` (or any route ending with .php) and `example.com/.env` return Nginx errors (File not found and 403 Forbidden).

`example.com/non-existing-image.jpg` also returns Laravel's 404 error as expected.

How can I modify the Nginx configuration to ensure that Laravel's 404 errors are returned in all cases, instead of displaying Nginx error messages for restricted or non-existent files?

Current nginx website config is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /srv/example.com/public;
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
    error_page 404 /index.php;
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
 
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```